How do I convince older academics to switch to MS Teams rather than using email?
I'm a postdoc and the most junior member in a multidisciplinary academic project. Currently the team's main form of communication is via email, which has become more and more chaotic recently. It's becoming increasingly difficult for everybody to keep track of all the threads of information.
I would like to create a MS Teams channel and ask all team members to use it as our primary source of communication, to consolidate our different information streams. I believe all members have access to MS Teams. However, I'm concerned about the blowback from such a request, as many of the older academics may not see the point of using it, being more familiar with email.
Does anybody have any experience with trying something similar, and any advice for how to be persuasive in making such a request?

Are you sure you’re not solving a problem that doesn’t exist in the group? Or overcommunicating? It would help your case to show gaps the group has and how this, or any new tool, is worth the investment learning.

This is probably a hopeless task. Many of my older colleagues have explicitly pushed back against use of Teams chat for communication (even from higher-level management), citing non-permanence of chat logs and difficulty in searching through it cf email. If they are happy with the way they are doing things, they won't see the benefit of changing.

MS Teams and eMail are suited for different kinds of information. Do you want to switch because the kind of information you exchange matches MS Teams, or "just" because people have access and it’s not eMail? At least judging from your description of communication being chaotic with many different threads, it doesn’t look like MS Teams has a fundamental advantage.

Note that MS Teams is not particularly pleasant to use if you're on Linux or, presumably, anything else other than Windows and MacOS. It works, but it isn't pleasant. I would really hate what you are suggesting, for instance.

Not me. My computer is a MS-free zone. See: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/terms-of-use. Most commercial offerings have similar issues. Their priorities are not your priorities.

Comment from older software dev. We once attempted to use Teams too - but it is not usable in our environment - it is chaotic, it makes increasingly difficult for everybody to keep track of all the threads of information, it is distracting, it does not allow efficient search for older information and so on and so on.

Note that the senior in "senior colleague" is not quite the same as the one in "senior citizen".

@Scriddie, the headline suggests "older". Perhaps as in older and wiser. ;-)

I am one of those older devs and I've never forgotten Joel Spolksy's advice about minimizing interruptions to stay in "the zone." (https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) It's important to use the right tool for the job: Email for asynchronous communication that isn't urgent. (Just because someone lacks patience and wants an answer right now doesn't necessarily make it urgent.) Chat for urgent things that are short and uncomplicated.  And a phone call or online meeting for urgent things that require back-and-forth discussion that is too much to type.

The  copying of large blocks of text is really terrible on teams. Why dont you try and copy a long (several pages) conversation? I find teams lousy for that.

Why use MS Teams?  So Microsoft can collect valuable data about us!

As someone with lots of experience with all kinds of tools, it's better to convince people to use email threads and labels properly and effectively than an entirely new system. The proliferation of different chat tools is a major turnoff - some of us have to track 6-7 different channels. Not a good argument.
Using chats effectively is another steep learning curve. E.g. Discord workflow is quite subtle and has lots of features that you have to train people to use properly. MS Teams may be disliked by people who dislike MS in general.
Short of high-end professional org tools (the usual suspects in software engineering come to mind) who make a compelling case, I  think less flexible academics won't see much gain with such a transition.
More chat-experienced people may gain a bit, but, to be honest, despite myself being an experienced user of chat systems for many  years, I am tempted to go to back to an almost entirely email-based communication for anything but the most quick and short-lived communication. At least, you can search for where some statement - that you distinctly remember - has been made without having to scour different chats, channel-associated file repositories, channels etc. which is something I had to do just recently.
This is complemented by Nelson and PLL's excellent additional argument: chat information ages and decays, sometimes catastrophically, for a number of reasons:

licenses limit the searchable time window
host and support change model or disappear
data export is limited, sometimes due to honest tech constraints, sometimes due to intentional "garden-walling"
owners of files/chat dropping out of reach

While it is possible to implement effective chat use and data organization by very rigorously applying workflow etiquette of a highly professional and disciplined well-oiled industry developer team, these latter people are paid for that level of discipline. Academics are not. Academics tend to focus discipline onto thinking, not onto organisation.
My recommendation would be to introduce discipline in the tool they know, that is, email, such as choosing good subject lines and keeping threading hygiene and leave it at it.

Agreed - I'm a pretty young academic and am also very reluctant to use teams over email in most cases.

Some of these downsides just don't really exist. Like the searching one. I've never had problems searching for stuff in even when I have no clue what channel, DM, or group chat it is in.
It feels like grasping for any any every reason possible to say no.
The main reason I'd say not to change is because there'll likely be some resistance to it for very little gain. Like this answer says there's plenty of tools and labels and setups that can be done to organize emails. That eliminates the need for any other tools imo.

The linking of attachments to onedrive is a giant disaster. Dealing with onedrive permission settings and then having stuff disappear is a nightmare to deal with. Even as an engineer, it gets missed, and if the colleague happened to have left the company, well, good lucky trying to deal with orphaned data in one drive.
Email attachments are MUCH simpler to deal with.

@TheEvilMetal: Searching in chat isn’t a big problem for current projects, but it ages terribly over time.  In chat-based projects, I’ve had all of the following problems, aside from remembering what platform they used: (1) the platform shut down and the history is lost; (2) history is only saved up to a relatively small limit; (3) history is saved, but past a small limit only searchable with premium subscription; (4) the app is outdated and barely-functional.  In my email, on the other hand, I have 20+ years of full history, all easily searchable.  There’s just no contest.

@TheEvilMetal Apart from the excellent aging arguments mentioned above, you say "I've never had problems searching for stuff..." - but that's exactly what happened to me once or twice in the past weeks. Wasting 20-30 minutes to find something that I was sure I had seen when I am going to a meeting where I need to know this - is no fun. A single repository is searchable, but multiple ones are not.

You see a problem and you're proposing a solution. Does the rest of the research group agree that this is a problem? For example, can you point to recent instances where someone missed an important update that was communicated by email (and, as a result, they wasted time/effort)?
If you can't, consider whether you should implement your own individual processes for tracking this information and working within email.
If you can, that's the place to start - not just in persuading others, but also your own problem-solving. Read the other answers carefully. I would encourage you to consider all of the specifics and ask yourself: Given the nature of the issue, and your collaborators' tools and tool access, what change in process produces the best results with the smallest change?

Exactly this. The first step should not be "convince my colleagues to use [my favorite software]", it should be "check whether my colleagues agree that there are significant problems with continuing to use [the current software]".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem ; if possible, bring the problem to the group (or other people in the group who agree with you that there is a problem) and try to come up with a solution (perhaps e-mail threading, perhaps Teams, perhaps something else) that works best for most people.

Any tools are as good as all people are able to learn them and want to use them properly.
The problem with cluttered e-mail is not the e-mail system. It's people cluttering the system.
I'm quite confident people messing up the communication via e-mails are about to mess the communication in Teams, Discord, post, etc. as well.
Another issue here is that e-mail or IRC are protocols, Teams and Discord are services.
With e-mail, one can use Outlook, another Thunderbird, another some hosting and still you can collaborate quite efficiently no matter what happens to Outlook or Thunderbird. When Teams fade, how can you access all the data sent through it? Do you remember AOL/ICQ? Skype?
If you want to clean the communication the best option, in my opinion, is to teach the members how to communicate efficiently. What they want to say, who are the recipients, what information to include and what not to include, etc.
Also think of assigning administrator duties and authority to someone, who will focus on the communication within the team.
You can look for request tracking system, where few people will administrate is and the rest will interact via e-mail only.

For me, the problem with email is not about communcation methods -- email versus chat. Asynchronous communication is fine for collaboration. The problem is maintaining accessible information over time. Email is generally designed around a paradigm of write, send, receive, archive, done.

In a collaboration, we often need to let a message "sit" for days or weeks while I think about the answer.
We also need to go back and read things like meeting notes or previous decisions we'd come to, often weeks or months later.
A long-running collaboration could have dozens of threads and hundreds of messages, and the subject lines of the email are often not that informative.
People tend to either try to maintain "Inbox Zero", so they want to archive read emails immediately, or they have very messy inboxes. Either way, it's often hard for most people to quickly access an older ongoing email thread.
The big provider email interfaces (Exchange, Gmail) are clunky, slow web interfaces often with poor support for organization and search, and people often don't use the organization tools.

We got our entire research group to switch to Zulip, which is a similar tool to Slack. It currently has a free plan for academic research. However, there were only a couple faculty and they were "young". The pitch was that this would be a place we can store and organize things like meeting notes, discussions about e.g. where to submit the paper or how to format a certain part, etc. Once we tried it, we liked it and we use it for almost all of our projects.
However, if this project is a small part of somebody's day and they don't feel there is a problem for them, they probably won't want to switch. So you'd need to try to politely raise the issues you perceive ("it's becoming increasingly difficult for everybody to keep track of all the threads of information"), raise the possibility that a different organization method is needed, and propose your solution. Maybe my points above about the drawbacks of email can help. Discussing it with your closest collaborator or two one-on-one first would be a good idea.

Your first two bullet points sound like email should be the tool of choice rather than chat (where "sitting" messages or messages from a week ago quickly scroll into oblivion). Your third point seems to argue for email with good subjects (rather than a huge chat with NO subjects), and so does your fourth (it may be hard to quickly access an older email thread, but so is to find an older topic/thread/separate chat in a chat tool). Point 5 is good, but Outlook/Thunderbird allow for a ton of productivity tweaking. So: are you arguing for email?

I'm saying there are good asynchronous alternatives to email, and I'm talking about email as it is used (not as we wish it were).
